# How NSValueTransformer works?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

In sample [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913), UIImage can be saved to database with core data tech.

NSValueTransformer is used to do conversion from UIImage to NSData, and vice verse.

But the question is that there is no obvious invocation of NSValueTransformer to do such converting in source codes. So just wonder that how this works ?

A interesting discussion can be referred [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42457-save-image-core-data.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NSValueTransformer is specified in the Recipes.xcdatamodel of the project.  If you open the .xcdatamodel in xcode, then click on Image  and then the image property (the type is transformable) and you can specify the  Value Transformer Class name in the gui tool.

Comment: correct,when I open .xcdatamodel I understood it. Pretty easy !